# Not able to set the value for setText

Tags: android

```
public class Cust_Details_address extends Fragment{
   String operator;
   EditText operator_name;
   @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details_customer_2, container, false);

     Intent intent=getActivity().getIntent();
     operator = intent.getStringExtra("operator");
     operator_name = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.operator_id);
     operator_name.setText(operator);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"operator"+operator,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return view;
  }
}
```

In Toast its showing the operator name but EditText is blank thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like `operator_id` is not inside layout `details_customer_2`

Comment: check your intent is null or not

Comment: intent is getting value

Comment: add `if(intent.getExtras() != null) {operator_name.setText(intent.getStringExtra("operator"));`

Comment: not able to set the value for EditText